# Creating a presto view on Glue table causing an error with invalid data type: integer

Tags: sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a table in Glue catalog table_a which has 2 columns -

| column | data type |
| --- | --- |
| emp_id | bigint |
| emp_name | string |
| age | int |

I am trying to create a presto view to query data on Athena.

```
create or replace view view_a
as
select emp_id, age
from table_a
```

When I query on the table, am getting the following error:

```
HIVE_INVALID_METADATA: Glue table table_a column 'age' has invalid data type:integer
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It means that somewhere in the data you have a value which is not `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I profiled the underlying table and that column age seems to have blank values. Would that be a reason as to why the view is throwing an error? How can i fix this? The blank values on the underlying table are historical data from DB2 and they can contain blank or null values

Comment: If the column contains anything apart from an integer or a null then you’ll get the error. What do you mean by “blank”  - a space, an empty string, a non-printing character?

Comment: It's an empty string. I tried removing empty string values from the table and tried recreating the same view. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by “empty string”, what’s the ascii value of the character in the field? How did you go about removing them - what was the SQL you ran?

Answer (score 0):

Likelihood is that the column `age` contains values that cannot be integers. Suggest you run a query like this to look for NULLs or non-integer values.

```
SELECT emp_id, age,
CASE 
    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'Null Value'
    WHEN CAST(age AS STRING) REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN 'Integer'
    ELSE 'Non-Integer'
END as age_type
FROM table_a
WHERE age IS NULL OR CAST(age AS STRING) REGEXP '^[^0-9]+$'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The table does have empty string values and I tried removing those values from the table and recreated the view. Am still getting the same error.